# which insertion sort is better.Either using a Outer for and while or two for loops.both are generating same outputs

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop, while-loop, insertion-sort

Using two `for` loops:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InsertionSort{
    public static int[] doInsertionSort(int[]a){

        int j=a.length;
        for(int k=1;k<j;k++){
            for(int i=k;i>0;i--){
                if(a[i]<a[i-1]){
                    int temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[i-1];
                    a[i-1]=temp;
                }
                //for printing the elements while sorting..
                for(int o:a)
                    System.out.print(o+" ");
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]arr={99,77,55,33,11,88,66};
        int []arra= doInsertionSort(arr);
        for(int i:arra)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    }

}
```

Using a `for` and `while` loop:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InsertionSortAgain{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]arr={99,77,55,33,11,88,66};
        int n=arr.length,j;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            j=i-1;
            int key=arr[j+1];
            while(j>=0 && arr[j]>key){ 
                arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                j=j-1;
                //for printing elements while sorting.....
                for(int k :arr)
                    System.out.print(k+" ");
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            arr[j+1]=key;
        }
        for(int k :arr)
            System.out.print(k+" ");
    }
}
```

I have tried both and both do fine, but I couldn't get which is optimized. 
And whether insertion sort can be implemented like this or not?

Comment: Why not time it and see?

Comment: Other than this being off-topic for StackOverflow you should ask yourself several questions: 1.) As @khelwood stated: Why not just time it? 2.) Why does insertion sort (which is unoptimized anyways) need optimization? 3.) Why not use an optimized sorting algorithm that is not of complexity O(n²)? 4.) Why not use the inbuilt `Collections.sort` over reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @khelwood i tried timing and found it almost same...

Comment: yeahh...@Ben that's right.But i doubted whether the first one is also a insertion-sort.because i've been learning it the 2nd way since.

Comment: If the time is almost the same, that suggests that the performance difference is not worth worrying about.

Comment: Typical stackoverflow - a guy asks a question and is asked to figure it out himself